# Should I avoid adding ngModel as one of the attributes to my angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

To properly work with `ngModel` I have to use `ngModelController`, but it provides much more flexibility than I need. Most of the time all I need is to have ngModel as yet another `=` attribute of the directive. So I often do this:

```
angular.module('oneClickRegistrationApp')
    .directive('myDirective', [function () {
       restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                ngModel: "=",
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
              //here I use ngModel as scope.ngModel
            }
    }]);
```

I feel that there are some potential downsides to this, but I can't pinpoint them.